# How to convert two double data type elements into one Point data type

Tags: c++

I am iterating over a vector that stores Point data type [x,y] in order to do some individual calculations on each x and y.... Subtracting x from vector element 2 from x from vector element 1.......To do so i convert these points into double data types.....Now i need to put them back into Point data type.....?

Sample Code:

```
double  Pta;
    double  Ptb;
    double vect;

    double PtResult;
    for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_a = Left_Arm_xy.begin()+1; iter_a != Left_Arm_xy.end(); ++iter_a)
    {


        if(center.y <= 240)
        {
            Pta = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
            Ptb = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;

            vect = ((Point)Pta, Ptb);

        }
```

Compiler indicates: "Error: no operators "=" matches these operands" at the very last line of code

```
vect = ((Point)Pta, Ptb);
```

Is such conversion possible if so can anybody suggest a solution...?

Comment: So you want to reconstruct a `Point` instance out of `Pta` and `Ptb`, or you want to modify an existing one? Please show the definition of `Point`, or at least its constructor prototypes.

Comment: Few questions is `vect` supposed to be a `Point`? Also the code sample you have `vect = ((Point)Pta, Ptb);` but later on you say the error happens on `vect = ((double)Pta, Ptb);` which contradicts the code sample.

Comment: Sorry for the typo regarding the last code information i edited it back to Point......And yes Thats my aim to reconstruct Point out of Pta and Ptb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Point` is just a simple structure containing `x` and `y` members, you could do something like this:

```
Point vect;
vect.x = Pta;
vect.y = Ptb;
```

Or more simply:

```
Point vect;
vect.x = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
vect.y = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;
```

Comment: your suggested solution works just as I wanted much appreciated...I did all the testing and everything works according to my "paper" calculations :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a `Point` from your two data points then `Point` just needs a constructor that takes two doubles as arguments and use that:

```
 Point vec(Pta, Ptb) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make vect a 2 vector, see changes below:

   ```
   double  x;
   double  y;
   Vec2   vect;
   Vec2   PtResult; // not used?

   for
   (
       vector<Point>::iterator iter_a = Left_Arm_xy.begin()+1;
       iter_a != Left_Arm_xy.end();
       ++iter_a
   )
   {


       if(center.y <= 240)
       {
           x = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
           y = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;

           vect = new vect(x, y);

       }
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: for clarity... the way you have it must be `Vec2` defined as pointer to `Vector`

Answer (score 0):

First of all wanted to thx everyone who tried helping me here everyone will get a vote up :P ....I managed to solve this particular issue using @Jorge Israel Pena suggestion....

Just though i share the final solution code sample:

```
double Pta; 
double Ptb;
Point  vect;
int i = 0;
for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_a = Left_Arm_xy.begin()+1; iter_a != Left_Arm_xy.end(); ++iter_a, i++)
{


if(center.y <= 240)
{

    vect.x = Pta = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
    vect.y = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;


    cout<<"Calculation No. : "<<i<<" ""Center Points: "" "<<*iter_a<<" ""Vector Addition Tail to Head: "" "<<vect<<endl;


}
```